# In WooCommerce I am getting Time Limit Reached error and it is canceling my order

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, woocommerce, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using the plugin of woocommerce for the payment gateway. My client selling the product from out of the country. When users want to buy anything it shows the error "Unpaid order cancelled – time limit reached. Order status changed from Pending payment to Cancelled.", and the order gets cancelled. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Following are the image-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3gpq.jpg)

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please show the error you are getting in the Question - don't use images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors